# python3 Why does max( listOfStrings) not return the longest element?

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, max

Im new to python. just started learning. but experimenting with it and with max() i now got stuck a bit. See this example:

```
list=["hello Wold", "hy", "xx", "ccc"]
max(list)
```

it returns

> 'xx'

*help(max)* tells me that given a single iterable argument its supposed to return its largest item. So i would expect to get the "longest" item back.

why is it not returning the longest item  in the list?

tanks for help

Comment: Why would it? `max(list, key=len)` would, but `'hello world' > 'hy'` is not true.

Comment: If you were to sort your list of strings, what would come first and what would come last? It is *that* order that `max()` looks at.

Comment: thanks for the duplicate info. i searched the site, but didnt found that solution myself. but it contains the 100% solution to me. thanks!